# write binary file using objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I hope to read/write a byte of a binary file.
Is it possible to access binary file and write/read a byte of the file using objective-c?
Just like C can do?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objective-C is a proper superset of C. Not only does it have its own file I/O methods, you can do exactly what you would do in standard C to access files.

Answer (score 5):

There is a class in COCOA called NSData. You can call "dataWithContentsOfFile" class method to load bytes from file into NSData object. Use "writeToFile:options:error:" to write bytes back to file.